# Why isn't the return value from my user defined function being written into a text file?

Tags: python-3.x

Just as the title states, I've been trying everything to get the results to be written into a file. May anyone please let me know what's going on? I would greatly appreciate it!

```
def convert_seconds(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds - hours * 3600) // 60
    remaining_seconds = (seconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60)
    return(hours, minutes, remaining_seconds)

convs = open("results.txt", "w")

koshka = input()

hours, minutes, seconds = convert_seconds(koshka)

convs.write(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Comment: You should specify what exactly is the problem. Are you getting an error? Is your file empty? Does it have wrong output?

Comment: Sorry about that. The file is empty after running the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three potential errors here. When I test this code, my first issue is that the captured `input()` is a string and it needs to be an int or a float (but that might just be how I'm running it). I fixed that by adding `seconds = int(seconds)` to the top of the function.

Next, `convs.write(hours, minutes, seconds)` throws an error because writ takes just one argument. It should be something like `convs.write(str(hours) + " " + str(minutes) + " " + str(seconds))` You could make that a lot more elegant but the point is you need the write object to be one string.

Lastly, running write() in w mode will "Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file." Presumably, you want to open the file and add your result to whatever else is there? If so, you should use "a" instead of "w".

Comment: Also, you forgot there not `close`ing the file

Comment: Thank you for replying! Furthermore, I wasn't aware that '.write' only take one arg so now I know!

Comment: Also, after making those changes it seems to work just fine now. I really appreciate all the help guys, I'm teaching myself Python and there's still a ton to learn but this definitely cleared things up a bit more for me!

Comment: @Carcosis Although appreciatable, no need for thank-you comments. If you want to show your appreciation feel free to up-vote and even accept the answer

Comment: @Tomerikoo Just accepted the answer, new to the site as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Carcosis No problem! All in good spirits. Feel free to take the [tour] and read about [ask] and the other links on that page